# How to enable LDAP with PHP 7.0 in Debian 7 wheezy server with directadmin

Tags: php, ldap, directadmin

How to enable ldap in PHP 7?
I have server with DirectAdmin

If I enter

```
apt-get install php-ldap
```

or

```
apt-get install php70-ldap
```

receives

```
root@www4:/usr/local/directadmin/custombuild# apt-get install php70-ldap
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package php70-ldap
root@www4:/usr/local/directadmin/custombuild#
```

If I enter

```
root@www4:~# apt-cache search php | grep ldap
```

receives

```
phamm-ldap - PHP front-end to manage virtual services on LDAP - back-end files
phamm-ldap-amavis - PHP front-end to manage virtual services on LDAP - back-end files
phamm-ldap-vacation - PHP front-end to manage virtual services on LDAP - back-end files
php-net-ldap - a OO interface for searching and manipulating LDAP-entries
php-net-ldap2 - PHP PEAR module for searching and manipulating LDAP-entries
phpldapadmin - web based interface for administering LDAP servers
simpleid-ldap - simple OpenID provider implemented in PHP - LDAP plugin
php5-ldap - Module with LDAP functions to PHP 5
root@www4:~#
```

Comment: have you tried php7.0-ldap?

Comment: @heiglandreas this same ... "E: The php7.0-ldap package could not be found
E: No package found by regular expression "php7.0-ldap""

Comment: What does`apt-cache search php | grep ldap` report?

Comment: @heiglandreas i edited the question with this command results

Comment: Where did you get PHP7 from? What does `apt list --installed | grep php` output?